# Import Backend services description into WSO2 APIM

Tags: api, wso2, documentation, wso2-api-manager, wadl

I'm working on a Java project, using SparkJava framework. I made REST web services, and now I'm trying to place WSO2 API Manager in front of my services.

The problem is that I don't know how to import the backend service description into WSO2 API MANAGER. I saw that this is often done with WADL, but in WSO2 APIM documentation (v2.5.0) there is nothing about this.

My goal is to generate some file which contains my Backend service description (I don't know what format should it be, or what tool must I use to do this), and be able to import it in WSO2 API MANAGER as my API documentation.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WADL was used sometime back, but now the common and the standard and way of representing a RESTful API is swagger/OAS.

In WSO2 APIM there are several ways you can create a proxy API for your backend service.

1) If you already have a swagger/OAS spec for your backend service, you can import it to APIM.

2) Create API from the scratch. In this approach, you can define resources and there parameters/headers etc. using the publisher UI.

Comment: Thanks Bee, yes I saw things about Swagger in the WSO2 APIM documentation.
I'll see what I can do to create or generate Swagger spec for my backend.